# On click of submit button, input text box icon is expanding, How to fix it using CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and jquery validation. In case of error, the inline icon is expanding. How can I fix it?

[registration page](https://www.masaz4you.cz/test_registration.html)

[image]

Comment: please add your css code too

Comment: can u plz share ur css code? ? Need to check..

Comment: Have you already tried to inspect the element, in order to check what is creating that little square?

Comment: It generally happens when fonts like `font-awesome` were not imported well in your site, so instead of icon it show these type of square boxes.

Comment: Without looking at your page, you are probably sticking the error message inside of the group and that is causing the group to be on two lines which makes the add on span two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `.help-block` elements are making the parent element higher.

Try this:

```
.help-block {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Its partially working, Size of textbox is not increasing but input box is not ready to accept input values due to error message inside the textbox. Please check.

Comment: Try change value of top property to 20px and add new declarations: font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer :) You can also rate it, to help me reach my score :)